# What qualifies collection of strings to become a line?

Tags: python

Following code is taking every character and running the loop as many times. But when I save the same line in a text file and perform same operation, the loop is only run once for 1 line. It is bit confusing. Possible reason I can think off is that first method is running the loop by considering "a" as a list. Kindly correct me if I am wrong. Also let me know how to create a line in code itself rather first saving it in a file and then using it.

```
>>> a="In this world\n"
>>> i=0
>>> for lines in a:
...     i=i+1
...     print i
...
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to loop over `a`, which is a string. Regardless of how many newlines you have in a string, when you loop over it, you're going to go character by character.

If you want to loop through a bunch of lines, you have to use a list:

```
lines = ["this is line 1", "this is another line", "etc"]
for line in lines:
    print line
```

If you have a string containing a bunch of newlines and want to convert it to a list of lines, use the `split` method:

```
text = "This is line 1\nThis is another line\netc"
lines = text.split("\n")
for line in lines:
    print line
```

The reason why you go line by line when reading from a file is because the people who implemented Python decided that it would be more useful if iterating over a file yielded a collection of lines instead of a collection of characters.

However, a file and a string are different things, and you should not necessarily expect that they work in the same way.

Comment: Thanks Michael for clearing things up, now I understand why the behavior was different.

Comment: @Abacus - No problem. If my answer worked for you, click the checkmark to the left of my answer to mark your problem as solved. (If the other answer to your question was more helpful to you then mine, then you should click the checkmark for that one instead).

Answer (score 0):

Just change the name of the variable when looping on the line:

```
i = 0
worldLine ="In this world\n"
for character in worldLine:
    i=i+1
    print i

count = 0
readFile = open('myFile','r')
for line in readFile: 
    count += 1
```

now it should be clear what's going on. 
Keeping meaningful names will save you a lot of debugging time.

Considering doing the following:

```
i = 0
worldLine =["In this world\n"]
for character in worldLine:
    i=i+1
    print i
```

if you want to loop on a list of lines consisting of worldLine only.